# Limit of a sequence within a logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers.

(1) Assume that $x_n>-1 \space \space \forall \space n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, show that $\log(x_n+1) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

(2) Assume that $x_n>0 \space \space \forall \space n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n \to x>0$ as $n \to \infty$, show that $\log(x_n) \to \log(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.

I managed to do the first one but I'm not sure how to go about the second one. A similar method didn't seem to apply.

In this question, $\log(x)=y$ where $y$ is the unique real number with $\exp(y)=x$. Where $\exp(x)$ is the limit of $(1+x/n)^n$ as $n$ tends to infinty.

The method I've used so far involves the inequality $1+x\leq e^x \leq 1/(1-x) \space \space \forall \space x <1$.

Comment: You should either show what you did for (1) or describe your definition of `log`. Or do both. Otherwise, the continuity of `log` is considered trivial.

Comment: What if $x_n=-1/2$? $\log(-1/2)$ does not make sense. Who is $x$?

Comment: @Argyll log as in base e. And I used the identity that 1+x<e^x<1/(1-x) for all x < 1

Comment: As in specifying what definition of $log$ you are required to use. For example, often first year analysis course define $log$ as the integration of $1/x$ in a particular way. I have the same recommendation as earlier.

Comment: @TitoEliatron thanks, I just corrected it

Comment: @Argyll oh, ok. I'm just told that log(x)=y where y is the unique real number with exp(y)=x

Comment: Sounds good. In that case, you will need to define what `exp` means. And with a complete definition, feel free to edit it in your question.

Comment: @Argyll alright, I've edited the op now. Is this sufficient?

Comment: I believe so. I would also add in what you have done. That helps attracting answers. (I'll need to sign off now. Hope you get an answer soon.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have proven that $\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\ln(x)-\ln(y)$ for $x$,$y>0$, then the proof is quite easy. We'll need the following result:

> **Lemma**: If $a_n$ is any positive sequence satisfying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln(a_n)=0$.

This follows from (1). If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-1)=0$, so by (1) we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(a_n-1+1)=0$. This is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(a_n)=0$, so we are done.

With this established, let's now consider the sequence $x_n$. It was given that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x>0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{x}=1$. It follows from our lemma that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{x_n}{x}\right)=0$, so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\ln(x_n)-\ln(x)\right]=0$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(x_n)=\ln(x)$$